# Infinite series: defining the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Consider the following sum described below:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(3+i)(2k-4-i)}}$$

Where $0 \leq x \leq 2k-8$  and even and $k\geq 5$ is a constant integer.

I need to find the closed form expression for this sum, however, after many attempts I couldn't. This would make it easier for me, because it makes up a function that I am proving to be increasing. Can you help me?

Comment: Whaat makes you think such a closed form exists?

Comment: for $x=2k-8$ Then; $$A=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3\left(\frac{k}{2}-1\right)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{4}-1}}\sum_{i=1}^{k-4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(3+i\right)\left(2-\frac{4-i}{4-k}\right)}}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(2k-4)}}+2\sum_{i=1}^{k-4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(3+i\right)\left(\left(4-i\right)-2\left(4-k\right)\right)}}$$ Try finding asymptotes maybe?

Answer (score 0):

To show that it is increasing, consider  $$a_i=\frac1 {\sqrt{(3+i)(2k-4-i)}}$$ and let $$b_i=\frac 1 {a_i^2}=(3+i)(2k-4-i)\implies b_{i+1}-b_i=2k-2i-8$$ So  $(b_{i+1}-b_i)$ is decreasing with $i$ for a given $k$ and so $(a_{i+1}-a_i)$ is increasing.

For a closed form, I am quite skeptical (even using special functions). But, this makes a nice looking function.